# Bootstrap Project Structure and Version Control

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, version-control

Bootstrap can be installed by zip, clone, or a package manager.

The total package includes source, docs, examples, and other build tools.

Built project code is put inside the `dist` directory.

What I cannot figure out is how to *"properly"* package a project using Bootstrap in either case of having existing code base or as an independent website...

Should I put just the contents in dist in version control?

**Or**

Is there a reason to store the entire package in version control?

If the latter than the package.json file belongs to Bootstrap rather than a personalized project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precompiled Bootstrap download looks like this:

```
bootstrap/
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

And Bootstrap source code download looks like this:

```
bootstrap/
├── less/
├── js/
├── fonts/
├── dist/
│   ├── css/
│   ├── js/
│   └── fonts/
└── docs/
    └── examples/
```

---

Note the following:

- The `dist/` folder contains everything listed in the precompiled download above.
- The `less/`, `js/`, and `fonts/` are the actual source codes for the CSS, JS, and icon fonts (respectively).

Your question is whether or not it is sufficient to simply include the `dist/` folder in your project, and yes, it is sufficient. But if you just want to use the precompiled Bootstrap without making any modifications to its source code, then you are better off simply downloading the precompiled Bootstrap in the first place. But if you want to work with and modify its source code for your project, then you have to include the entire package.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the in-depth response! Being that bootstrap is designed to get projects "off the ground" as quickly as possible I'd think that the build tools "baked in" are intended to be re-used by projects. For example, additional style sheets SHOULD utilize the same build tools and be minimized along with the other main bootstrap files. With that said, I don't see a simple way to upgrade bootstrap if files and build instructions start getting added to the core package (outside ./dist). Any suggestions?

Comment: You can place additional stylesheets separate from bootstrap, and modify/upgrade bootstrap on its own. See [customizing bootstrap the right way](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/) for some examples. Make your custom stylesheets load after the bootstrap stylesheet so that, if you override the bootstrap settings, your stylesheets take precedence. This way, you don't have to worry about upgrading, since the default bootstrap itself is untouched, and can simply be replaced during upgrade.

Comment: I actually did stumble upon that. I suppose then it's best to just setup independent build scripts, less, etc... Thanks again!

Comment: You can look into [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for modifying your build scripts in order to handle both bootstrap and your custom stylesheets, since bootstrap also uses Grunt. Try this link: [writing an awesome build script with Grunt](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-awesome-build-script-grunt/). And you're welcome.